# is it possible to import soundfie in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

I'm doing

```
import soundfile as sf
```

and I get the error:

> ImportError: No module named soundfile

I'm using Python 2.7 in Windows 10. I already did:

```
pip install pysoundfile

pip install conda

pip install virtualenv

python -m virtualenv venv

pip install numpy

pip install cffi
```

in the Windows cmd but no luck...I also tried:

```
pip install libsndfile
```

but I get the error:

> Collecting libsndfile   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement libsndfile (from versions: ) No matching distribution
>   found for libsndfile

did anyone try this?

Answer (score 0):

Execute:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then execute all above package commands again with prefix `pip2`

Comment: thank you, but I'm using Windows 10, those look like ubuntu commands, right? What would be the windows equivalent?